# install script to run then reboot and continue

Tags: linux, bash, automation, centos, boot

I have a script that is a pre installation script for a specific piece of software. the script takes care of a lot of the pre-requisites of the installation as well as kernel configuration.

What I am trying to do is create a set of scripts that automates the entire installation of this software and what I would like to know is if there is a way to have a script reboot the box and then ONE TIME kick off the second script that will execute the post reboot commands automatically to complete the installation.

I have several boxes I need to run this on (in excess of 40-50) and would really appreciate a way to do such a task where i can run the first script and have it take care of the reboot and completion of install.

Any ideas?

Comment: Let your script create an init script (and insert it into all runlevels that should be able to continue the installation). That script can, when it finished whatever it does, delete itself. Problem solved. Needs root priviliges though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to add the script path in `/etc/rc.local`, that way, the script will be ran @reboot